# TOMCAT keep running same war file glitch

Tags: java, apache, file, tomcat, war

hi im getting an error when running my .war file, but when I edit the file from eclipse save and export (overwrite) to apachesoftwarefoundation/tomcat 6.0/webapps and run from bin the same results pop up in my local host browser. but when I delete the file from the above location, theres no way it can access my server but guess what? start tomcat go localhost and I see the same webapp.. must I reinstall tomcat every time I wanna run a new war file???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> when I edit the file from eclipse save and export (overwrite) to apachesoftwarefoundation/tomcat 6.0/webapps and run from bin the same results pop up in my local host browser

Tomcat server comes up with a basic caching mechanism ( very basic ) and whatever it caches and holds are kept in the `work` directory. So you can either clean your `$Tomcat_Dir/work$` directory after launching your application or you can just make sure that your browser is not caching anything. Most of the time, it is the browser that is caching pages and we can't see updated changes immediately over the browser. I suggest to clear cache everytime you deploy your application.

I can suggest a work-around (if you don't want to clear your cache manually everytime), instead of pressing `F5` for refreshing the web-page, make a habit of re-freshing with pressing `CTRL+F5`. This forces a cache re-fresh on the current page.

Answer (score 1):

Delete that war file from webapps/ directory. Then open link `http://localhost:8080/` in your web browser. Click Tomcat Manager then enter user name and password. usename- root , password-root (I think by default).

If you can see your web application under Applications", undeploy it by clicking  `Undeploy`. Then in next page you can see one option called "WAR file to deploy". Select your new war file from there and click "deploy" button.

Also clear your web browser cache too before testing.

No need to restart tomcat after this process.

Answer (score 0):

To run your war file after updating something,you need to stop and restart or tomcat server each time you update anything.